# Dynamic Nested structure in GoLang

Tags: go

I am learning golang and want to write generic response from microservices response.

My General Response is like:

```
type GeneralResponse struct {
    Success string
    Message string
    Data    string
    Error   string
}
```

In the `Data` section I want to return any json, say list of `Person`, `Instruments` or any type of objects.

But it should be another json. 
I tried assigning other json objects but it did not work.
It is fine if I dump json array as string into it but it should unmarshal from receiver end.
How should I go about it?

I am trying over here. https://play.golang.org/p/dc0uKtS76aA

Comment: Post the json that you are trying to use here

Comment: [json.RawMessage](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) if you want to ensure that the value can be encoded, otherwise interface{}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use RawMessage in the type definition

```
type GeneralResponse struct {
  Success string
  Message string
  Data    json.RawMessage
  Error   string
}
```

and subsequently push a `Marshal`led json into that attribute. 
You can do that by encoding other types in `[]byte`s and setting them to the `Data` attribute.

Like in https://play.golang.org/p/CyoN5pe_aNV

Comment: I am sorry if I could not write proper question. Actually I need Data to store only one type of value but Dynamically. Not just  Person or just Instruments.

Comment: How do I push? Can you write a pseudo code. I tried google, but not sure.

Comment: Thanks it resolved my query! I will update question soon with solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you put marshalled JSON into a string, it will be marshalled as a string (because it's a string) and the receiving end will have to unmarshal it twice (because it's been marshalled twice). What you want is probably more along the lines of:

```
type GeneralResponse struct {
    Success string
    Message string
    Data    interface{}  // interface{} can be anything
    Error   string
}
```

This way you can put any data into `Data` and it will be marshalled directly into the response.

Answer (score 0):

json.RawMessage comes to rescue in case you wants to capture whole json without knowing its format.

```
type GeneralResponse struct {
    Success string
    Message string
    Data    json.RawMessage
    Error   string
}
```

Checkout this [code](https://play.golang.org/p/eKKsmrEVJl8). I have modified your code to dump data into response

Comment: No reason to use pointers to RawMessage. RawMessage is already a slice type. It's much more inconvenient to work with pointers, because they can't be used as a []byte.

Comment: How do I dump a json array in Data now?

Comment: I have added code by modifying the data and dumping array into interface{}

Comment: You are showing code using interface{} , I thought it should be RawMessage?

Comment: you wants to dump data json.RawMessage is used when you are not using any underlying type to get the value. Here you are already using slice[]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json.RawMessage` for that.
I have implemented the encoding part, you find more here to decode - https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage